# JavaFX: use only one scene or multiple scenes to build UI with static and dynamic content?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, scene

cheers,

i am fairly new to JavaFX2. I already did some research about the basic principles: Stages that contain Scenes. Scenes in turn can be switched. But only switching parts of scene does not seem to be common usage.

My Problem: 
I am trying to create an application with a titlepane (containing a lable and some buttons) and a Pane containing further dynamic content. The titlepane will stay there throughout the whole lifecycle.

Now i am confused about what is the best way to achieve such a layout. I found some ideas [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23629876/6403991) to make my root layout a Borderpane and switch its center. In that case i would end up with only one scene. But i am not shure if that´s how it should be done.

Any help and ideas on this topic is very appreciated.
cheers tobi

P.S.: i am using FXML files to create my layout and Controller to handle each view.

Comment: is there no one who could suggest me some best practice approaches? Help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is this question: [Loading new fxml in the same scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619394/loading-new-fxml-in-the-same-scene), which is (perhaps) a duplicate of yours.  I wouldn't call the solution there a "best practice", but it is likely decent enough for a smallish app.  The answer provides a [small framework](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130) for swapping fxml controlled content panes in and out of a portion of the main scene.

Similar is Angela's [Managing Multiple Scenes](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1).

More comprehensive solutions are things like [Gluon Desktop](http://gluonhq.com/products/desktop/) (which I haven't used) or [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com).

For an actual non-trivial application, look at the [SceneBuilder application](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/apps/scenebuilder), which is probably the best "best practice" reference you could find for a decent sized JavaFX application. But, as it is non-trivial, [understanding its architecture](http://ladstatt.blogspot.com/2014/01/home-made-javafx-scenebuilder.html) is likely non-trivial too.

Comment: i took a look at sceneBuilder application. Is there anything like a tutorial on how to use it ?

Comment: thanks... is used angelas approach and changed it according to my requirements.

Comment: Tutorials can be found by [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=javafx+scenebuilder+tutorial).