# JavaFX Scenebuilder: How to connect pages with each other?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am working on a JavaFX project and the problem that I am facing is that I can't connect the different pages for my application. I can't go from another FXML file to another FXML File. For example I have two FXML Files. One for the Login Screen and one for the Menu. What I want is that when I click on the login button of my Login screen that I immediately go to my Menu Screen.

Comment: You would do that in the controller.

Comment: Problem is it doesn't work in the controller. That is why I am asking haha. I am exporting different files from my team, but they somehow can't connect with each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login Application with 1 stage and multiple scene in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627340/login-application-with-1-stage-and-multiple-scene-in-javafx)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description, and no-one can really tell you what you're doing wrong from what you have posted in your question. The correct way to do this is from the controller code. I recommend you create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* and *complete*) that shows what you have tried and what is not working and [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to transition from one screen to another is to assign a new `Scene` to a `Stage` using the `setScene` method of Stage.

Another way is to assign a root node like BorderPane to the `Scene` and swap `FXML` using its set methods(`setTop`, `setCenter` etc.) as per your application needs (In your case, on logging in).