# What to know before starting to learn JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I read about the advantages of JavaFX over Swing(that is not the point of discussion) and I would like to learn JavaFX.
But later I got confused between the JavaFX script and other things like XML, etc... 
I don't have a clear picture of it yet.
I want to know what all things like basic information and programming/markup languages one must know before giving a try at JavaFX.

Comment: You can do everything directly in Java if you want to. You can also use FXML files to configure your UI layout (only very basic knowledge of XML required) but you don't have to.

Answer (score 23):

Well, as far as I am concerned, I would say **nothing is mandatory**, before you start learning Javafx. Just a small knowledge of `JAVA` would be enough (just the basics)

For Javafx learning resources, Oracle has one of the best available resources, enriched with lucrative examples, which will make your **Journey of learning Javafx** fantastic.

The fxml files are basically the UI which can be written using XML and can be loaded in your code. This makes your application follow the **MVC** rule. Though initially, I would recommend to spend sometime constructing your UI using java code only.

*For more info on FXML*

[Java vs JavaFX Script vs FXML. Which is better way of programming in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828037/which-is-better-way-of-programming-in-javafx/22828398#22828398)

*Tutorials on Javafx*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

*For Beginners*, Getting Started with JavaFX is very important !

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784

*Tutorial on Scene Builder* i.e. making fxml files for your application,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/get-started-tutorial/overview.htm

*Tutorial on FXML*

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I started learning JavaFX last summner and it is really great and easy to use. I don't think you should know anything before start learning. A little bit xml knowladge can be beneficial but I don't think it is necassary because JavaFX secene builder generates .fxml files generically. So you can directly start using it.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But I want to learn the language properly and thoroughly. I don't know much about the Scene Builder, but is it difficult to build application without using it?

Comment: Please share some good resources for learning JavaFX.

Comment: No you don't have to use scene builder and you can use it directly in Java but SceneBuilder really makes jobs easier. I recommand it to use but as I sail you can also code it in Java. Besides, if you use Eclipse, you can download e(fx)clipse from eclipse market to have JavaFX libraries. The book I have learned JavaFX is this;
http://www.amazon.com/JavaFX-Beginners-Guide-ebook/dp/B004QWY5YA

Comment: xxlali, one more question. :) That book which you suggested mentions JavaFX script which is not in use now, I think. Is it safe to use that book even today to learn JavaFX?

Comment: When I study, I have never seen JavaFX script. Maybe editions are different so I don't know :)

Comment: [link](http://www.amazon.in/JavaFX-Beginners-Guide-J-F-Dimarzio/dp/0071077340/) . This is the link I used. I guess the editions are same. It has all about .fx files which are script files bro. :/

Comment: I am sorry for giving wrong resource. Now, I checked and 
http://www.amazon.com/JavaFX-2-0-Introduction-Example-Experts/dp/1430242574
is the book I have used. I am sorry again. :(